# Android java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent

Tags: java, android, exception, service, broadcast

As soon as my application starts I get a crash and I can't figure out why. I have a `Service` that is used as a timer to count the number of seconds since the timer started, this then gets passed back to my `MainActivity`.

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "BroadcastTest";
    private Intent intent;

    private Chronometer timer;
    private Button start;
    private Button stop;
    private EditText hourlyRate;
    private TextView money;
    private long timeWhenStopped = 0;
    private double moneyEarned;
    private double secondsRate;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        timer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
        start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
        stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);
        hourlyRate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.hourlyRate);
        money = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.money);

        intent = new Intent(this, Timer.class);

          start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Timer.class));
                timer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + timeWhenStopped);
                timer.start();

            }
        });

        stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                timeWhenStopped = timer.getBase() - SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                timer.stop();
            }
        });

        timer.setOnChronometerTickListener(new Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer){
                long timeElapsed = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - timer.getBase();
                int seconds = (int) timeElapsed / 1000;

                double hrlyRate = Double.parseDouble(hourlyRate.getText().toString());
                secondsRate = (hrlyRate / 60) / 60;

                moneyEarned = secondsRate * seconds;

                double displayMoney = Math.round(moneyEarned * 100.0)/100.0;

                Log.d("hours",Long.toString(seconds));

                money.setText("$"+Double.toString(displayMoney));

            }
        });

        }

    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            updateUI(intent);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        startService(intent);
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(Timer.BROADCAST_ACTION));
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
        stopService(intent);
    }

    private void updateUI(Intent intent) {
        String counter = intent.getStringExtra("counter");
        Log.d("SERVICE_SECONDS", counter);
    }
}
```

**Timer.java:**

```
public class Timer extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "BroadcastService";
    public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION = "b.calvin.com.dirtymoney";
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Intent intent;
    int counter = 0;

    private Runnable sendUpdatesToUI = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            countSeconds();
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000); // 1 second
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdatesToUI);
        handler.postDelayed(sendUpdatesToUI, 0); // 1 second

        Toast.makeText(this, "service starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return START_STICKY;
        }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    private void countSeconds() {
        Log.d(TAG, Integer.toString(++counter));
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

**Error:**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: b.calvin.com.dirtymoney, PID: 3348
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=b.calvin.com.dirtymoney flg=0x10 } in b.calvin.com.dirtymoney.MainActivity$4@bf337ff
at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:891)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:139)
at b.calvin.com.dirtymoney.MainActivity.updateUI(MainActivity.java:113)
at b.calvin.com.dirtymoney.MainActivity.access$600(MainActivity.java:20)
at b.calvin.com.dirtymoney.MainActivity$4.onReceive(MainActivity.java:93)
at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:881)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: You are passing wrong intent through broadcast receiver. It generate null pointer exception on updateUI() in MainActivity

Comment: Explain? I dont understand sry

Comment: You are not pass any extra data through your intent  in broadcast receiver. But your updateUI(Intent intent)  in Mainactivity check for an extra string but not fount anything and raise null pointer exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you forgot to put your `counter` variable into the `Intent`, so you're passing `null` to `Log.d()` as the message, resulting in a `NullPointerException`.

Something like this should work:

```
private void countSeconds() {
    Log.d(TAG, Integer.toString(++counter));

    Intent counterIntent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);
    counterIntent.putExtra("counter", counter);

    sendBroadcast(counterIntent);
}
```

Also, counter is an `int`, so you should call `getIntExtra()` instead of `getStringExtra()`:

```
private void updateUI(Intent intent) {
    int counter = intent.getIntExtra("counter");
    Log.d("SERVICE_SECONDS", Integer.toString(counter));
}
```